# Set default gtk event globally

Tags: event-handling, gtk, mouseevent, pygtk

I want to connect the event onMouse-move  to the method mouse_move in the class event_mod.py

I want to set this changes to be the default in all applications using gtk.

Is this possible ??

Answer (score 1):

Not in PyGTK in any case.

What you can do is try creating a dynamically-loaded GTK module, like Ubuntu does with their overlay scrollbars, or [GtkParasite](https://github.com/chipx86/gtkparasite) does to create a widget inspector.